# In GKE all logs are labelled with the wrong severity in the airflow worker pod

Tags: logging, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine

I am working in order to deploy airflow (using the airflow helm chart) on a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster.

When dag runs, all the logs in the worker container are labeled by GKE with severity=“Error”, although the logs do not refer to an error and all the dags succeed (see screenshot).

I have looked online for similar issues, but I couldn't find any answer.

[image]

Comment: Why do you not use directly `Cloud Composer` ? There is any reason to manage and install Airflow yourself ? In this case, there is less compatibilty with other Cloud services compared to a managed Airflow with Composer.

Comment: How do you use the logs from the `DAGs` and `Airflow` code ? With `Python` `logging` ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun sorry maybe my question was not clear, i edited and added a screenshot on my question. As you see the logs are not the one setted by me in the dag codes, but are the airflow internal logs. As you see from the screenshot the logs are tagged by airflow as INFO, but gke shows them as Error.

Comment: Ok I understand? I think intenally `Airflow` uses the default `Python` `logging` and it causes this issue with `Cloud Logging`. Why do you not directly use a managed solution like `Cloud Composer` ?

Comment: Could you provide a simple example to reproduce this?